# How can I convert this cURL request that send a file to an API into a PostMan request?

Tags: http, curl, postman

I have the following problem. I can perform the following request via **cURL**:

```
curl -F file=@"C:\\FE_example.xlsx" http://localhost:8080/api/comp_vibr_and_temp_tab
```

and it works fine. As you can see I am attaching a file to a POST request (the expected format for the file is MultiPart). The value returned by this API is a JSON.

Using the previous cURL command it works fine but trying to perform the same request via PostMan I obtain an error.

In PostMan I set the file into the **Body** section. Into the **Header** section I set:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

Trying to perform the request I obtain the following error message:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1581890120091,
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
    "message": "Required request part 'file' is not present",
    "path": "/api/comp_vibr_and_temp_tab"
}
```

Why? What is wrong? How can I convert my **cURL** request into a correct **PostMan** one?

Answer (score 1):

[image: In form-data tab by selecting file option you can browse any file]

[image: Content-Type must be multipart/form-data]

You can try above steps to resolve your problem.